# protractor e2e testing for data sorting involving two column

Tags: protractor

I have to verify if priority is same for two operations then it should be sorted as operation name. Using protractor.
 I tried this for verifying priority sorting but it is not working

```
this.Then(
    /^Verify operations in with priority sorting ascending$/, function(callback) {
        var sorted = [] , unSorted = [],i=0;
        var OperationPriority = element.all(
                by.xpath('//table/tbody/tr//dx-number-box/div/input'));

        console.log("count" +OperationPriority.count);

        // OperationPriority.each(function(eachName){
        OperationPriority.map((eachName) =>{
        // eachName.getText().then(function(name){
            unSorted[i] = eachName.getText();
            i++;
            console.log("high");
            console.log(unSorted[0]);
        });

        sorted = unSorted.slice();
        sorted.sort(); 

        console.log(sorted);
        console.log(unSorted);

        // expect(sorted).toEqual(unSorted);
        callback();
});
```

Comment: Please format your code properly!

Answer (score 1):

You need to know all Protractor APIs are **Async** and return **Promise**.

Like `getText()` not directly return the text of element, but return a promise which eventual value is the text of element.

Like `count()` not directly return the length of found elements, but return a promise which eventual value is the length of found elements.

To use the promise eventual value for computing, you need to consume them inside `then()`

```
this.Then(
    /^Verify operations in with priority sorting ascending$/, 

    function(callback) {

        var priorities = element.all(
                by.xpath('//table/tbody/tr//dx-number-box/div/input'));

        // approach 1
        // change below  priorities.getText() to priorities.getAttribute('value')
        // when priority display in an input box            
        priorities.getText().then(function(unSorted){
            var sorted = unSorted.slice().sort();
            expect(sorted).toEqual(unSorted);
        });

        // approach 2
        priorities.map(function(item){
            // change below item.getText() to item.getAttribute('value') below 
            // when priority display in an input box
            return item.getText();
        })
        .then(function(unSorted){                              
            var sorted = unSorted.slice().sort();

            console.log('unSorted: ' + unSorted);
            console.log('sorted : ' + sorted);

            expect(sorted).toEqual(unSorted);                
        });

        callback();
});
```